# Write picture from canvas as jpeg

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to write picture from a canvas as jpeg.

I have image as png format bytes:

```
  PictureRecorder recorder = new PictureRecorder();
  Canvas c = new Canvas(recorder);
  c.drawPaint(paint); // etc
  Picture p = recorder.endRecording();
  ByteData pngBytes =
      await p.toImage(100, 100).toByteData(format: ImageByteFormat.png);
```

Is it possible to convert png to jpeg or use some other function instead toImage()?

Comment: see https://pub.dev/packages/image

Comment: i saw it, but i have problem that there is other image class defined than i recive from ui.image when convert picture to image

Comment: i have no idea what you mean

Comment: you can import it like this to avoid the conflicting naming `import 'package:image/image.dart' as myCustomeNameImage;`

Comment: PictureRecorder return Image from dart:ui

Comment: but `toByteData` returns raw bytes

Comment: ``final rawBytes = await img.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.rawUnmodified);``

``var dir = await getExternalStorageDirectory();``

    ``var path = dir.path + "/appname/test.jpg";``

   `` final buffer = rawBytes.buffer;``

   `` var r = await File(path).writeAsBytes(
        buffer.asUint8List(rawBytes.offsetInBytes, rawBytes.lengthInBytes),mode: FileMode.write, flush: false);  ``

  ``  await r.create(recursive: true);``

I done something like this but the file not created

Comment: and where do you use any encoder from that library?

Comment: now i have problem with writeAsBytes

Comment: no, you have the problem because you are not using [image](http://pub.dev/packages/image) package at all - you have to use [encodeJpg()](https://pub.dev/documentation/image/latest/image/encodeJpg.html) for example (or [JpegEncoder](https://pub.dev/documentation/image/latest/image/JpegEncoder-class.html) explicitly)

Comment: for use  encodeJpg() I need image from package image.
I still dont know how get it from rawBytes
`final rawBytes = await img.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.rawUnmodified);` 
I could do:
`var jpgData = IM.encodeJpg(
        IM.decodeImage(rawBytes.buffer
            .asUint8List(rawBytes.offsetInBytes, rawBytes.lengthInBytes)),
        quality: 100);` but the quality isn't so good.